# Неверный ответ webhook (302 Found) от Telegram бота в PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot, .htaccess, telegram, mvc

Всем доброго времени суток! У меня есть MVC сайт на PHP. Суть проблемы в том, что при получении ответа webhook Телеграм отправляет сообщение об ошибке - **Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found**.

- Вебхук успешно был зарегистрирован по ссылке https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/setwebhook?url=https://mysite.ru/webhook.
- SSL: сертификат Let's Encrypt.

*Результат метода getWebhookInfo():*

```
    [ok] => 1
    [result] => Array
          (
                    [url] => https://mysite.ru/webhook
                    [has_custom_certificate] => 
                    [pending_update_count] => 8
                    [last_error_date] => 1658579570
                    [last_error_message] => Wrong response from the webhook: 302 Found
                    [max_connections] => 40
                    [ip_address] => x.x.x.x
          )
```

Предполагаю, что проблема таится в htaccess.
В корневой папке есть htaccess (1) и запросы в перенаправляются в папку public. А в htaccess (2) запросы отправляются в index.php. Сам новичок. Заранее благодарен всем, тем кто поможет в решении данной проблемы.

*Структура папок:*

```
 - app
 - ---controllers
 - ---models
 - ---views 
 - config
 - public
 - ---files
 - ---css, js
 - ---index.php
 - ---htaccess (2)
 - vendor
 - composer.json
 - htaccess (1)
```

*htaccess (1):*

```
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

*htaccess (2):*

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

    php_flag session.use_trans_sid Off
    php_flag session.use_only_cookie On
    php_flag session.auto_start On

    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 604800
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 604800

    Options -Indexes
```

Comment: Webhook не следует по редиректам, убедитесь что адрес, по которому он идёт - конечный.

Comment: Код контроллера страницы mysite.ru/webhook `<?php namespace app\controllers; use Telegram\Bot\Api;
class WebhookController extends AppController { public function indexAction() {
        $telegram = new Api('TOKEN'); $update = $telegram->getWebhookUpdates();

        @file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tmp/bot_log.txt', print_r($update, 1), FILE_APPEND);
       
        debug($telegram->getWebhookInfo());
    }
}`

Ответ getWebhookUpdates() пустой объект: 
`Telegram\Bot\Objects\Update Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array()
)`

Comment: @daniel-protopopov Заранее извиняюсь за мое не понимание темы, но можно поподробнее об понятии адрес конечный? в моем случае сайт на MVC